# Is there a simple way to get performance information from a remote Windows 2012 R2 machine via HTTP?

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I would like to keep an eye for performance and usage for a Windows 2012 R2 machine I have in AWS.  The machine is visible (RDP) from the Internet, and I would like to be able to quickly see the Task Manager information (for example via a browser).

For example, to watch which users are connected (it is a Terminal Server), I was thinking on running quser and get the standard output posted by an specific ASPX page (this would imply that my machine security group opens port 80, of course). The ASPX page name would be password, because the page would be open to the Internet.

Which are my options to quickly get usage and performance data from the Task Manager without actually RDPing as Administrator to the machine in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would create a powershell script which runs locally on the server (you can get nearly unlimited informations with ps) and put all infos you want to have in a xml file, which will be safed in you inetpub folder...

So you will be able to look at this file via internet. You will be able to secure the access via htaccess or something similar. But even when it is public the information would't be so risky if you only provide the info of CPU Usage an RAM usage etc. in the XML file.

The Powershell Script could run automatically via task planning every 1-5 minutes for example...

this is only how i would make it. But it depends which info you exactly want so see...

But this solution sould be simple in my opinion...